# SQL Server 2005 Full text search - Searching for numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I using the SQL Server 2008 FTS feature in a project. When searching for a phone number like `CONTAINSTABLE(table, *, '"017394708699"')`, this query also returns records containing the number '`017394689966`', which is similar. Does anyone know how I can get an exact match from a number?

Comment: Could you please post a full T-SQL example? It would be useful to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of the operation you are performing.

The value 0173946899 is contained within **0173946899**66.

You may have more success using a postfix:

CONTAINSTABLE(table, *, '"*017394708699"')